# I have an issue with a variable not updating before being printed

Tags: python-3.x, debugging

```
 def updateDecisionScreen():
    print (OpponentHealth)
    DecisionScreen = ('''
Your opponent currently has {} HP; You have {} HP; It is your turn.

[1][Melee Attack]   <-000::000->  [2][Block With Sword]

[3][Ranged Attack]  <-000::000->  [4][Gain Distance]

[5][Try to Escape]  <-000::000->  [6][Exit The Game]
    ''').format(OpponentHealth, PlayerHealth)
    print (DecisionScreen)
    return (DecisionScreen)
while (OpponentHealth > 0 and PlayerHealth > 0):
    updateDecisionScreen()
    print (DecisionScreen)
```

Prints this:

```
75

Your opponent currently has 75 HP; You have 100 HP; It is your turn.

[1][Melee Attack]   <-000::000->  [2][Block With Sword]

[3][Ranged Attack]  <-000::000->  [4][Gain Distance]

[5][Try to Escape]  <-000::000->  [6][Exit The Game]


Your opponent currently has 100 HP; You have 100 HP; It is your turn

[1][Melee Attack]   <-000::000->  [2][Block With Sword]

[3][Ranged Attack]  <-000::000->  [4][Gain Distance]

[5][Try to Escape]  <-000::000->  [6][Exit The Game]
```

Why is this the case? I see absolutely no reason for that to be happening. I have been looking at it for an hour now and I can't seem to find and reason for it to be un-updating like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summary: You have a function that returns a value. you are not assigning the function to a variable to receive the value back. That's why it is printing that information out. Also the variable `DecisionScreen` outside the function is out of scope. So it will not print anything.

Here's whats happening with your while statement.

You have two variables with values

```
OpponentHealth = 75

PlayerHealth = 100
```

You are calling the function `updateDecisionScreen()`.

The first statement in the function has a print statement. `print (DecisionScreen)`

So it prints out `75`

The next statement is the definition for `DecisionScreen`

Then you are doing `print (DecisionScreen)`

So it prints out the full formatted data.

The next is return statement with the value from `DecisionScreen'

It returns back to the while statement.

Within the while statement, you are not assigning the value back to a variable. So it is pushing the value out to the console.

If you have a function that has a return statement, you have to assign the function to a variable.

Does this make sense?

Comment: if this helped you understand it better, please upvote.

Comment: I don't yet have enough points to upvote answers, but I did mark it best answer for now. I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Because you declared the variable DecisionScreen inside a function and then call it outside the function in the print (FightersImage + DecisionScreen). The scoped of the DecisionScreen variable is only inside of the function.

Comment: I have it declared the same way outside of the function before the function as well.